# Check if history.back() doesnt navigate

Tags: javascript

I have a custom back button

```
<button type="button" class="back">back</button>
```

I have an event listener on the button that when clicked calls history.back() to go back to the previous page.

```
var backbtn = document.querySelector(".back");
backbtn.addEventListener("click", goBack);

function goBack(){
    history.back();
    // i need to check if there is no option to go back
}
```

When there is no option to go back I want to hide the back button. How do I check if there is no previous page in the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by simply checking `window.history.length` to get the count of navigation history.

Here's the updated code:

```
var backbtn = document.querySelector(".back");
backbtn.addEventListener("click", goBack);

function goBack(){
  if(history.length>1)
   {
    history.back();
    // i need to check if there is no option to go back
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.history.length` to get the number of entries in the browser’s history stack. If it is equal to 1 (the current page), then you can’t go back.

Answer (score 1):

Check history length:

```
var x = history.length;
```

If the length is 1 you can hide the button.

Note: The property returns at least 1, because the list includes the currently loaded page